# Plotly - Changing dropdowns disables groupings for boxplot

Tags: r, plotly

I'm creating a boxplot with dropdown options for the variable that gets plotted on the y axis. The data has 4 "people", and each observation has a type A or B. For each person 1:4, the chart plots bars for the observations A and B (example: https://plot.ly/r/box-plots/#grouped-box-plots).

I'm able to create it, but once I change the dropdown the groupings all get messed up. Here's example code:

```
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)
x <- rep(1:4, 6)
y1 <- rnorm(24, 5, 2)
y2 <- rnorm(24, 2, 5)
type <- rep(c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A"), 3)

df <- data.frame(x, y1, y2, type)


p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~x) %>%
  add_boxplot(y = ~y1, color = ~type, name = "First") %>%
  add_boxplot(y = ~y2, color = ~type, name = "Second", visible = F) %>%
  layout(
    boxmode = "group",
    title = "On/Off Box Plot",
    xaxis = list(domain = c(0.1, 1)),
    yaxis = list(title = "y"),
    updatemenus = list(

      list(
        y = 0.8,
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE)),
               label = "y1"),

          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE)),
               label = "y2")))
    )
  )

p
```

The dropdown starts with y1 and looks exactly how I'd like, but changing the dropdown regroups the data and changing back to y1 doesn't get back to the original graph.

**Here's what's happening to the groupings:** After changing the dropdown, `y1` groups all type "A" with `y1` and `y2` plotted next to each other. Option `y2` does the same but uses type "B" data. I only want `y1` data for both types A/B (like the original graph).

I'm guessing the ' boxmode = "group" ' line is getting lost during the switches, but I can't get it to work. Does anyone know how to maintain the groupings based on `type`? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updatemenus` should be length 4, because there are actually 4 traces (2 visible at a time). Note that for groups, each legend item has a corresponding trace. Unfortunately R's automatic repeating of vectors obscures this.

ie, the value for `updatemenus` should be:

```
updatemenus = list(
  list(
    y = 0.8,
    buttons = list(
      list(method = "restyle",
           args = list("visible", list(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)),
           label = "y1"),

      list(method = "restyle",
           args = list("visible", list(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)),
           label = "y2")))
)
```